# OpenID OWIN auth and lack of user permissions

Tags: azure, owin, openid-connect

I may be handling this totally incorrect, but I am using OpenID with MS Azure to authentication my users, then I check to make sure the user has a user account in the notifications of the OpenID middleware, if the user is not found, I am throwing a security exception.  How do I return a **You do not have access to this applicaiton** type page.  Am I just missing the hook?

Here is the example:
https://gist.github.com/phillipsj/3200ddda158eddac74ca

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use try...catch inside the notifications, something along these lines:

```
SecurityTokenValidated = (context) =>
{
   try
   {
       // retriever caller data from the incoming principal
       var username = context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.FindFirst(ClaimTypes.Name).Value.Split('@')[0];
       var database = DependencyResolver.Current.GetService(typeof (IDatabase)) as IDatabase;
       var employee = database.Query(new GetEmployeeByUsername(username));

       if (employee == null)
       {
          throw new SecurityTokenValidationException();
       }
         // I add my custom claims here
         context.AuthenticationTicket.Identity.AddClaims(claims);
         return Task.FromResult(0);
   }
   catch (SecurityTokenValidationException ex)
   {
       context.HandleResponse();   // This will skip executing rest of the code in the middleware
       context.Response.Redirect(....);
       return Task.FromResult(0);
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I will give this a try sometime today.